# Using include as root layout node throws "Error inflating class include" exception

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to use different list item layout depending on the OS version.

So, I created different layouts associated with conditions.
One of them is (in `layout/search_result_list_item.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<include xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1">
</include>
```

it includes the standard "simple_list_item_1".

In my Java code, the layout is associated to the list like this :

```
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                                      R.layout.search_results_list_item,
                                      null,
                                      from,
                                      to,
                                      0);
```

When a list item is displayed, the following exception is thrown :

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class include
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
   at android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.newView(ResourceCursorAdapt
```

What is wrong ? can't  be used as a root item ? despite ADT allows it.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but did you try using the root as a linear layout with fill_parent for both height and width, and having the include inside that.

Comment: Yes, maybe it could work, but I would not like to overload my list view useless intermediate views (one for each row).

Comment: Then dont define your own xml, just pass simple_list_item_1 to the adapter instead of yours

Comment: The purpose is to use different layout according to the OS version

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I'm having the same problem. Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 33):

If anyone else is wondering this is the answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge>
    <include xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1">
    </include>
</merge>
```

Comment: Yep, having a `<merge>` tag as the root element lets you inflate the layout without problems. Thanks!

Comment: I get `<merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true`

Comment: @MickeyTin you are probably either trying to use the inflate method with the 3rd parameter (attachToRoot) set to `false`, or using the `<merge>` tag as a root as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039162/android-xml-merge-layout-error-on-inflate)

Comment: Doesn't work with custom attributes - [Include layout with custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265258/include-layout-with-custom-attributes) **|** [Data binding does not support include as a direct child of a merge element.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide Android OS verion specific resources using qualifiers on the resource folders.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

The last item in the list of possible qualifiers is version (API level).