# Include layout with custom attributes

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a complex layout and I want to use `include` tag for my custom component, like this:

```
<include layout="@layout/topbar"/>
```

The `topbar` layout has custom root component and in layout xml file it's defined like this:

```
<my.package.TopBarLayout
 ... a lot of code
```

Now, I wanna pass my custom defined attributes to "topbar" like this:

```
<include layout="@layout/topbar" txt:trName="@string/contacts"/>
```

And then get the value of those custom attributes in custom component code or ideally in xml.

Sadly, I cannot get value of `txt:trName` attribute to make it to the `topbar` layout, I just don't receive anything in code. If I understand correctly from [that documentation page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html), I can set no attributes for layouts used via `include`, but `id`, `height` and `width`.

So my question is how can I pass my custom defined attributes to layout which is added via `include`?

Comment: [Data binding does not support include as a direct child of a merge element.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I came across it and found that it is now possible thanks to Data Binding.

First you need to enable [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#includes) in your project. Use `DataBindingUtil.inflate` (instead of `setContentView`, if it's `Activity`) to make it work.

Then add data binding to the layout you want to include:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="title" type="java.lang.String"/>
    </data>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/screen_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="center">

    ...

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@{title}"/>

    ...

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Finally, pass the variable from the main layout to the included layout like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        ...
    </data>
    ...
    <include layout="@layout/included_layout"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        app:title="@{@string/title}"/>
    ...
</layout>
```

Comment: it is working? how can you bind from xml? When i try this there was no text in included layout

Comment: @Andrzej It works for me so you must be missing something, maybe something I forgot to add to my answer. Can you post your code so I try to figure out whats wrong?

Comment: This does work, but indeed makes you dependent on data binding which may be more difficult to debug than the custom view approach described in another answer (which relies more heavily on compile-time checks)

Comment: @sapth You are right about the debugging but by using data binding you also avoid many bugs that result from updating the UI from several places in the application. You also avoid many calls to update UI from the code.
The main drawback for me is the lack of support for data binding by jack, which prevents me from using Java 8 features.

Comment: Is it possible to bind data from java ? Like "inflate this layout with `title="foo"`"

Comment: how put a custom attr in include tag?

Comment: [Data binding does not support include as a direct child of a merge element.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

Comment: Make sure you have the <layout> tag in your main (the parent) layout as well, or it won't be compiled

Comment: @DanChaltiel You can do this, if you want hardcoded strings.
`app:title='@{"foo"}'`

Comment: if you want to pass in two titles, it is impossible then.

Comment: @has19 yes it does. if you have a specific problem please post a question.

Comment: In order to make it work, you need to keep in mind that databindings must be enabled and it has to be inflated via `DataBindingUtil.inflate`, not just a regular view inflate. But yes, it works.

Comment: Data BInding was introduced in API level 14, Android 4, IceCreamSandwich

Comment: I made a silly mistake of having `app:title="@string/title"` instead of `app:title="@{@string/title}"`

Answer (score 10):

It's not possible to attributes other than layout params, visibility or ID on an include tag. This includes custom attributes.

You can verify this by looking at the source of the LayoutInflater.parseInclude method, around line 705:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#640

The inflater only applies the ID and visibility attributes to the included layout.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this issue today. For whatever it is worth, I think there is a straight-forward work around. Instead of adding attributes to the include tag, create a custom wrapper view for the include and add attributes to that.  Then, do the include from the wrapper.  Have the wrapper class implementation extract the attributes and pass along to its single child, which is the root view of the include layout.

So, say we declare some custom attributes for a wrapper called SingleSettingWrapper like this -

```
<declare-styleable name="SingleSettingWrapper">
    <attr name="labelText" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Then, we create two custom view classes - one for the wrapper (SingleSettingWrapper) and one for the child (SingleSettingChild) that will be included -

```
<!-- You will never end up including this wrapper - it will be pasted where ever you wanted to include. But since the bulk of the XML is in the child, that's ok -->
<com.something.SingleSettingWrapper
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    custom:labelText="@string/my_label_string">

    <!-- Include the child layout -->
    <include layout="@layout/setting_single_item"/>

</com.something.SingleSettingWrapper>
```

For the child, we can put whatever complex layout in there that we want.  I'll just put something basic, but really you can include whatever -

```
<com.something.SingleSettingItem
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout >
        <!-- add whatever custom stuff here -->
        <!-- in this example there would be a text view for the label and maybe a bunch of other stuff -->
        <!-- blah blah blah -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.something.SingleSettingItem>
```

For the wrapper (this is the key), we read all of our custom attributes in the constructor.  Then, we override onViewAdded() and pass those custom attributes to our child.

```
public class SingleSettingWrapper extends FrameLayout 
{
    private String mLabel;

    public SingleSettingWrapper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                                                             R.styleable.SingleSettingWrapper,
                                                             0, 0);

        mLabel = a.getString(R.styleable.SingleSettingWrapper_labelText);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public void onViewAdded(View child)
    {
        super.onViewAdded(child);
        if (!(child instanceof SingleSettingItem))
            return;

       ((TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.setting_single_label)).setText(mLabel);
        /*
        Or, alternatively, call a custom method on the child implementation -
        ((SingleSettingItem)child)setLabel(mLabel);
        */
    }
}
```

Optionally, you can implement the child too and have it receive messages from the wrapper and modify itself (instead of having the wrapper modify the child as I did above).

```
public class SingleSettingItem extends LinearLayout
{
    public SingleSettingItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setLabel(String l)
    {
        // set the string into the resource here if desired, for example
    }
}
```

At the end of the day, each of the XML files where you wanted to `<include>` your layout will contain about 7 lines of XML for the wrapper+include instead of the single include that you wanted, but if the included view contains hundreds of lines you're still way better off. For example -

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- this is the beginning of your custom attribute include -->
    <com.something.SingleSettingWrapper
        android:id="@+id/my_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:labelText="@string/auto_lock_heading">
        <include layout="@layout/setting_single_item"/>
    </com.something.SingleSettingWrapper>
    <!-- this is the end of your custom attribute include -->
</LinearLayout>
```

In practice, this seems to work pretty well and is relatively simple to set up. I hope it helps someone.

Comment: A little bit too complex with wrapping a view into view

Comment: This is the approach I've taken as well, since there is no support for layout inheritance. I'm now attempting to style included elements (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211576/passing-style-references-to-a-merge-layout), however I may have ran into a bug (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211138/styling-a-view-with-a-custom-style-reference/52251717).

Comment: @RomanTruba You don't need to wrap a view in a view. Just extend the view. For example, extend TextView and use YourCustomTextView in place of TextView

Comment: @ChrisSprague I'm not sure that you understand the problem here. The layout in include is already complex

Comment: @RomanTruba I use a very similar approach fairly often and it works well. The above explanation is a bit more complex than it needs to be and can be cleaned up, but the general concept is good. Specifically, when done correctly, there is no reason to state, "You will never end up including this wrapper".

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, the only thing I can contribute is that I was also unable to set custom attributes on an include tag, and have them pass through to the included layout.

It may well not be possible at this point.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use  with custom attributes, or any attributes other than the ones stated on the API page (up through at least 5.0.0):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38023

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java

Answer (score 0):

You have to include in your root xml element your custom namespace.
If your package name is com.example.test your xml shold be something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:txt="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.test" />
```

A nice tutorial is: http://blog.infidian.com/2008/05/02/android-tutorial-42-passing-custom-variables-via-xml-resource-files/

Comment: Thank you, but I know it, and namespace is included. Problem is attributes not passed to component

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. After visiting this thread, I ended up using `View`'s `setTag()` methods to attach identifying information to each `View` during `onCreate()`, and then `getTag()` methods to retrieve it later on.