# Static data-binding in Android [literals]

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have created **custom layout** which contains image and title. To reuse this layout I'm using `<include>` tag. The problem is that I'm not even able to **bind string literal** into the layout being included. I tried to follow these  [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265258/include-layout-with-custom-attributes#answer-38681418), but without success.

*layout/titlebar.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="title" type="String"/>
        <!-- <variable name="imgSrc" type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable" /> -->
    </data>
    <LinearLayout ... >
        <!-- <ImageView ... android:src="{imgSrc}" /> -->
        <TextView ... android:text="@{title, default=DefaultTitle}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

*layout/otherlayout.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              ... 
              >
    <!-- bind:imgSrc="@{@drawable/some_image}" -->
    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"
             bind:title="@{Example}"  <---------- does not work 
             />
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

In gradle I have enabled data-binding for module:

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This should work, make sure you are binding that xml in your Activity/Fragment

Comment: @RaviRupareliya so I need to bind data from Activity class? I though that passing string constant does not require to writing something in class. Is there any way how to bind constant from xml?

Comment: I have not tried it but atleast you need to bind your xml i guess. Still i am not sure but you can give it a try with binding of Activity like `DatabindingUtil.setContentView(this,<activityLayout>);`

Comment: @RaviRupareliya `DatabindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.otherlayout);` does the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed *layout/otherlayout.xml* based on @CzarMatt answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 
layout with bindings has to be wrapped in <layout> tag so {LayoutName}Bindings 
class can be auto-generated for binding purposes 

xmlns:alias="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
creates an "app namespace" for custom attributes
-->
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout  ... >
        <!-- 
        // if this layout is also using title "data variable" 
        // and we want to use default value if title is null
        bind:title='@{title ?? "Settings"} 

        // passing literal reference into the binding
        bind:title="@{@string/settings_constant}"
        -->
        <include layout="@layout/titlebar"
                 bind:title='@{"Settings"}'
                 />
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Data-binding requires to set layout via `DataBindingUtil` as @RaviRupareliya suggested, otherwise data-binding will not work:

```
public class OtherActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        // setContentView(R.layout.otherlayout);
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.otherlayout);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Variables may be passed into an included layout's binding from the
>   containing layout by using the application namespace and the variable
>   name in an attribute

This means that, the following data variable must be included in both your `titlebar` and `otherlayout` XML files:

```
<data>
    <variable name="title" type="java.lang.String"/>
</data>
```

and the `<include>` should look something like this:

```
<include layout="@layout/titlebar"
       bind:title="@{title}"/>
```

Refer to Data Binding docs for more information:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#includes