# Duplicate class found in the file '/activity_login.xml' DataBinding, BR not being generated

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel, android-databinding

I mostly being stuck with android data binding BR issue. There is single activity.xml always but generated binding class showing error. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: I have same problem. And I can not build my project. Compiler say that can not find symbol com.mypackage.example.databinding.MyActivityBinding

Comment: did you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes. By adding android.databinding.enableV2=true in Gradle properties

Comment: For me, the ..Binding file is marked as invalid only if it is opened. In any case, the build succeeds... When I do clean and rebuild the error disappears. Just don't open the generated binding file that's all.

Comment: you can take a screenshot instead of taking pictures from your mobile

Answer (score 6):

Custom binding class name resolved my problem

```
<data class="ContactItem">
    …
</data>
```

Comment: Where did you add this?

Comment: Inside the layout tag

Comment: Worked for me, too. I don't know the reason, which class was duplicated. Here is the reference for the renaming of the ViewDataBinding: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding#custom_binding_class_names

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the Room ORM
Check your DAO clazz

Example:

@Update
    String update(Call call);//fail

```
@Update
long update(Call call);//fail

@Update
int update(Call call);//success databinding build


@Update
void update(Call call);//success databinding build
```

Comment: thanks for post... I was also face this problem but i was using give string to primary key which cause the problem

Answer (score 2):

I'd it by adding android.databinding.enableV2=true in Gradle properties. It was working fine.

Comment: Not working. It's only happing when I add kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$roomVersion" on build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and it was because I had a reference to a variable of an unknown class

```
<variable name="handler" type="com.example.org.UnknownClass" />
```

I just had to correct this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the **Room ORM**, review them if you've recently had some changed. Any problem in parsing `SQL` queries and also return type of your method that should fully match with the query result can affect on data binding and show unnormal errors.

I had a similar problem:

```
@Query("SELECT * from NotSellingReason where NotSellReasonId > 0")
    List<ReasonModel> getUnvisitingReasons();
```

I had a wrong generic type here. I must used `ReasonEntity` instead of `ReasonModel` and it takes a long time to get it!

> Another problem which can fail the data binding is about **Dagger
>   DI**. If you are using DI in your project be sure that all injected
>   classes, ... are provided or bound by the dagger.

Comment: in my case i have made the @Entity class variable declaration in one line (like private double min,max,degree;)and started getting this error and after this post  and another related to room, so I made the change in multiple line declarations for each variable(like private double min;private double max;private double degree;) and rebuild it and install the app.

Comment: First when I read this I find it irrelevant. But actually this is problem in my case. Thank you so much !!!!!!!!

Comment: Holy freaking waste of time, I was removing unused resources and deleting a few classes, thinking Dagger would pick up on the missing dependencies, NOPE DataBinding error out of the blue. 20 seconds of sorting out Dagger after 2 hours of rebuilding/cleaning and searching.

Comment: In my case I have a wrong return for my query method.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was the problem with Dagger 2 version. 2.17 and above (The latest version as of today is 2.20) didn't work. Changing back to 2.16 solved the problem for me.

See more discussion about this [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1245)

Comment: This solved my problem. I can build and run my app.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this error when you include a layout in xml.

```
<include layout="@layout/any_layout" />
```

to include another layout in your xml, follow this
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/38681418/1893503

Answer (score 2):

I was getting 37 of this duplicate errors, and it was all due to a wrong import in 1 layout file

```
    <import type="android.view.View"/>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="wrong.package.name.SViewModel"/>
```

I found it by opening all my layout xml files and checking it manual. The error itself was totally unrelated though, as it is still there if I manually go to /build/generated/data_binding..., but build doesn't fail anymore and no reports no errors or warnings.

Comment: Yes, It's a chance

Answer (score 1):

In my case this problem was caused by the fact that in Entity class of Room ORM names of setter and getter of private field did not match with java bean naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was happening because i changed `List` to `ArrayList`;
Issue resolved when changed back to `List`;

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM " + PurchaseConstants.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY purchaseTime DESC")
    List<Purchase> getAllPurchases();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case I was using **Room** and I did not write setter method in `Entity` class. So you also check in your case.

Answer (score 1):

in my case the problem was because of private modifier for onclick method assigned with  butterknife ,make sure all fields and methods assigned with butterknife are public

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was because the ARouter not support kotlin very well。when I use @Autowired annotation ，build failed and tips dataBinding not found ，duplicate class found in

the file ActivityLoginBinding。Then add @JvmField before @Autowired，It works and build success。

so，when you use AndroidStuido conver Java to Kotlin，Be careful，Kotin files generated in this way may have syntax errors。It could be some Java static function, the annotation of the @bindingadapter in databinding, converted to kotlin, and you get an error.Solve this, and you're done

for example in Java

```
 @BindingConversion
    public static String converStr(CommonUser user) {
        return user.getAge() + user.getName() + user.isSingle();
    }

    //同上，不需要显示因如何调用，在xml中即可使得textview有一个 bg 的属性，app命名空间的，
    @BindingAdapter({"bg"})
    public static void randomName(TextView tv, String color) {
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }
```

when use this in kotlin,like this:

```
//this is root node in the kotlin file ,no {} 
@BindingAdapter("srlEnableRefresh")
fun randomName( tv:TextView, color:String) {
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color))
}
```

or

```
object Tools{
   @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("srlEnableRefresh")
    fun randomName( tv:TextView, color:String) {
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color))
    } 
}
```

I hope this answer answers your question.My English is Very Poor ! ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Kotlin + dagger + data binding in my project. This approach should work irrespective of dagger2 version.

Things I did to fix my issue:

1. made `android.databinding.enableV2=false` in gradle.properties file and clean & rebuild
2. was able to see the actual error related to dagger2 incorrect scope
3. Fixed my dagger graph and other import statements
4. set back to `android.databinding.enableV2=true`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using room persistence library ,check again about it code. İ was get same issue and  after looking my code and i saw. This issue about room persistence..

Finally ..
İ am using Room Persistence library ,i am check my all code and i found. Check your  room model class.

Answer (score 0):

for me replace kapt to annotationProcessor worked

```
annotationProcessor "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this problem. You can try this command. worked:）

```
gradlew build
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A better answer would explain why this works, and why it's different from other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Also stumbled on this and damn, it sucks when it happens. Fair way, i'd go these two ways:

- because the binding is not fully generated, you might not get to the interesting build errors (like room trying to generate you it's boilerplate), therefore you should increase -Xmaxerrs flag for maximum number of shown errors
- in my case, the inspiration came to switch to another Android Studio and Gradle plugin version (in AS 3.4, beta channel, i got the actual build errors)