# How to pass custom attributes to nested xml

Tags: android, android-custom-view, attr

I have structure like that:

preferences.xml:

```
...

<com.example.MyCustomPreference
    ...
    myCustomMessage="@string/abc"
    android:inputType="..."
    ... />

...
```

preference_my_custom.xml:

```
<LinearLayout ...>

    <com.example.MyCustomView
        ...
        app:myCustomMessage="?????"
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

view_my_custom.xml:

```
<GridView ...>
    ...EditTexts, TextViews, etc.
</GridView>
```

I would like to pass myCustomMessage's value (I omitted other attributes for simplification) from MyCustomPreference to MyCustomView using XML. MyCustomView reads custom attributes, so I would like to avoid reading attributes in MyCustomPreference programmatically, getting TextViews from MyCustomView and setting them values. However, I really don't know what to type in place of "?????".

How can i do this using XML? Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include layout with custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265258/include-layout-with-custom-attributes)

Comment: I've seen it. I think my question is slightly different. I don't use <include>, and I don't want to use a reference to a resource, but a value which has already passed as an attribute.

Comment: Your question is slightly different but as far as I can tell the solution is the same (Data Binding)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it programmatically (unless you use `data binding`). For example, in your `MyCustomPreference` you catch de attribute `myCustomMessage`:

```
String myCustomMessage = null;
TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCustomPreference, 0, 0);
try {
  myCustomMessage = a.getString(R.styleable.MyCustomPreference_myCustomMessage);
} finally {
  a.recycle();
}
```

Here you got the `String` value of your attribute. Then, I supose you have inflated your `MyCustomView` inside your `MyCustomPreference`. As an example:

```
View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.preference_my_custom, this);
MyCustomView myCustomView = (MyCustomView) findViewById(R.id.you_custom_view_id);
```

So, here you can set programmatically your `myCustomMessage` in your `MyCustomView`.

```
myCustomView.setMyCustomMessage(myCustomMessage);
```

You should create this method to set correctly your text, and if necessary propagate this text to other child views of your `MyCustomView`.

Now, changing your `String` resId in your `preferences.xml` the interface should update as expected.

P.S: Since I don't know all your resource ids, please adapt them to your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and accurate explanation. Maybe there is no way to do it as simply as I expected, but this solution works perfectly and you have also mentioned data binding, so I can accept your answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Create an attribute file for your customeView:

**Add in attrs.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomView">
    <attr name="width" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Used in your customView init:

```
 public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView, defStyle, 0);
    mWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CustomView_width,0);
    a.recycle();
}
```