# Passing data from one layout to another

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm trying to reuse a keypad button with passing the numbers i.e. 1-9 and some letters under the number i.e. "abc", "def" etc. For some reason I can't get that working. Below you can see the code and everything that I've done. I've read all over the internet but just can't get it working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="mainText"
            type="String"/>
        <variable
            name="subtitleText"
            type="String"/>
    </data>
    <FrameLayout android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_round">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@{mainText}"
            android:textSize="44sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/latoregular"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@{subtitleText}"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/latoregular"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

I'm reusing the component here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
...

 <include
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            layout="@layout/keypad_layout"
            app:mainText="@{@string/keyboard_1}"
            bind:mainText ="@{@string/keyboard_1}"
            app:subtitleText="@{@string/keyboard_1_subtitle}"
            />
...
</layout>
```

and finally i've added data binding enabled in build.gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here - [Include layout with custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265258/include-layout-with-custom-attributes/38681418)

In order to make it work, you need to keep in mind that databindings must be enabled and it has to be inflated via DataBindingUtil.inflate, not just a regular view inflate. But yes, it works.